# Particles floating above procedural surface

Tags: modeling, particles, bump

I am trying to add particles to a surface over which I have added a texture and they look like they are floating in the air. I know this is because they are sitting on the actual model but is there a way to get around this?
[image: layout]
[image: render view]
[image: nodes]
[image]

Comment: This is interesting. I don't think the particle systems can get access to this kind of information. Given the "simpleness" of the displacement, you could use an actual pre-rendered wave texture inside a Displace modifier, which in turn can be accessed by the particle system. You can also use a Wood texture for instance and tweak the settings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gorgious says, it seems like the particle system can't take the *Displacement* node into account, in that case what you can do is baking the current displacement setting:

- Unwrap you object with the *Smart UV Project* option
- In the *Shader Editor* plug the wave texture only
- Create a new *Image Texture* node, create a new *32-Bit Float* image, keep the node selected:

[image]

- Bake with *Bake Type > Emit*:

[image]

- Here is what you should get:

[image]

- Create a *Displace* modifier, put it above the *ParticleSettings* modifier, choose *Coordinates > UV*:

[image]

- Load your texture:

[image]

- In the *Shader Editor*, replug only the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

- It should work:

[image]